# How to subtract list 1 from list 2?

Tags: java

There are two sheets, **list1** and **list2**:

```
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add("1/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d4.jpg");
    list1.add("1/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg");
    list1.add("1/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d6.jpg");

    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add("1/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d1.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z");
    list2.add("1/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d2.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z");
    list2.add("1/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z");
```

How to subtract **list1** from **list2**, but at the same time ignoring the date that is in **list2** at the end of the line **::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z**?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Scary Wombat  I've tried a lot, tried to use the map but it doesn't work.

Comment: Well unless you show what you have tried, it is impossible to tell you where you are gojng wrong.

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: @Scary Wombat I can remove duplicates in one list ignoring the date. But I cannot subtract list 1 from list two and ignore the date.

Comment: Try split all elements of second list by `:::`. It gives you an array of two elements: source and date. Then you can make a third temporary list of source elements so you will be able to subtract it.

Comment: @Prog_G ["1/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d1.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z", list2.add("1/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d2.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z"]

Comment: `list2.removeIf(e -> list1.stream().anyMatch(ee -> e.startsWith(ee)));`

Comment: `list1.forEach(list1Element -> list2.removeIf(list2Element -> list2Element.contains(list1Element)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you can look for items in list1 which are prefixes of each item in list2:

```
list2.removeIf(e -> list1.stream().anyMatch(ee -> e.startsWith(ee)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it java 8 Streams as below :

```
list2 = list2.stream().filter(i -> !list1.contains(i.split(" ::: ")[0])).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: it was interesting to benchmark the 3 codes that mentioned (including mine) and seems like your code is by far faster than the other 2

Comment: That's really interesting.., :)